# Force Javascript array to Float32

Tags: javascript

I'm working with WebGL, so I need `Float32Array`s all the time. Is there a way to force an array to be a `Float32Array`? I tried this:

```
var cubeVertices = new Float32Array(3 * 4 * 6);
cubeVertices = [
   /* Vertices */
];
```

But this appears to change the type to a `Float64Array`, since I can't use it with WebGL, but it works when I do a `new Float32Array(cubeVertices)`. I don't really want to use the `new Float32Array` command all the time, since it allocates memory that is of no use, because I don't need several copies of my data.

So is there a way of creating a `Float32Array` **without having two arrays**, where one is never used again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kind of created my own solution out of these answers, so that there aren't two arrays wasting memory. I use the `Float32Array.from` function and create a local array there that should be deleted after that line, so my code looks like this:

```
var cubeVertices = Float32Array.from(
  [
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5
  ]
);
```

Thanks to Akxe, using `Float32Array.of` would be even better, but it is not very widely supported.

Comment: Not the best of solutions... `Float32Array.of(0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5);` would work better

Comment: @Akxe what does it change?

Comment: @Akxe also of is not supported by Safari, which is an important browser

Comment: It would prevent create the intermediate array... If you know the length upfront why don't you want to use the normal constructor? It will work best. PS: Really sorry to hear you need Safari

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 ways to create the actual `Float32Array`:

- `new Float32Array(length)`
- `TypedArray.from(source[, mapFn[, thisArg]])` [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from)
- `TypedArray.of(element0[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])` [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/of)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be correct for you.

```
var num=[6676.88,8878.99.....];
var floatVal=num.map(function(value){
     return Math.fround(value);
});
console.log(floatVal);
```

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem, it just creates an other array and by that point I can just do a `new Float32Array`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
Float32Array.from(yourArray);
```

The `from` method converts Array-like objects to Float32Array and is available for other Array types on javascript, like Array, Float32Array or Int16Array.

You can read more about this on the "Indexed Collections" of the following URL:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: I edited the question, so that it becomes more clearer, that I don't want to just form a new array form an old one

Comment: have you tried `cubeVertices = Float32Array.from(cubeVertices)` after creating the array?

Comment: But thats also useless, it just creates a new array